# Neo4j Cypher Query To C# using 'WITH'

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I want to get client who has two accounts, one is Type1 and another is Type2. Cygher query is as below

---

```
MATCH (client:Client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(type:Type) 
With client, account, type
MATCH (client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account1:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(:Type{accountType: 'Type1'}) 
,(client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account2:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(:Type{accountType: 'Type2'})
RETURN client, account, type
```

---

it works(any enhancement is welcome, but this is not my issue )

How I can convert it into C#? particularly 'With client, account, type' part. I had Neo4j.client

I managed to do this,

---

```
StringBuilder queryString =new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder addtionQuery = new StringBuilder();

            queryString.Append("(client:Client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(type:Type)");

            addtionQuery.Append(String.Format("(client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account0:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(:Type{{accountType: '{0}'}})"
                , searchCriteria.acctTypes[0]));

            for (int i = 1; i < searchCriteria.acctTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (searchCriteria.acctTypes[i] != null)
                {
                    addtionQuery.Append(",");
                    addtionQuery.Append(String.Format("(client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account{1}:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(acct_type{1}:Type{{accountType: '{0}'}})", 
                        searchCriteria.acctTypes[i], i));
                }
            }


var query = Dbclient.Cypher
                .OptionalMatch(queryString.ToString())
                .With((client, account, type) => new 
                {
                    client = client.As<Client>(),
                    type = type.As<Demo1.Models.Type>(),
                    account = account.As<Account>()
                })
                .OptionalMatch(addtionQuery.ToString())
                .Return((client, account, type) => new QueryResult
                {
                    cif = client.As<Client>().cif,
                    type = type.As<Demo1.Models.Type>().accountType,
                    accountId = account.As<Account>().accountId
                })
                .Limit(searchCriteria.limit)
                .Results;
```

---

it works but result is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your queries are different. Your Cypher query has `MATCH` clauses while your Neo4jClient query has `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses, and you have different names for your nodes (account, account1, account2, ... <-> account, account0, ...).

I suggest you make sure that both queries are the same. You can use a debugger or print the resulting Cypher query with `query.Query.QueryText` or `query.Query.DebugQueryText`. In this case `query` is what you get before you call `.Results` on it, but your variable name is a bit off.

As far as `WITH` is concerned, the `With()` method can take a `string` as a parameter too, so you can simply write:

```
.With("client, account, type")
```

IMO, The `With()` that takes a lambda offers little or no gain over the one that takes a `string`, it's just more noise.

Comment: query.Query.QueryText or query.Query.DebugQueryText did help, I replaced 2nd optionmatch with match, it works now. cool

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the c# neo4jclient API, but your statement might be more efficient like this:

```
MATCH (client:Client)-[:OWNED_BY]-(account:Account)-[:TYPE_IN]-(type:Type) 
WHERE type.accountType IN ['Type1','Type2']
With client, collect([account, type]) as accounts
WHERE size(accounts) > 1
RETURN client, accounts
```

Comment: thanks mate, you query is more efficient but there is an issue is that it may return client has two accounts which both are type1/type2. I need client has 2 accounts with different types.